# intersection issues with rectangles

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to get the aliens to intersect with the shooter and when the intersection takes place, I want to exit the game. However, they pass right through the shooter at the bottom without the code even executing

This is my code:

```
Rectangle rectlauncher = new Rectangle(launcherXPos, 720, launcherImg.Width, launcherImg.Height);
Rectangle rectinvader = new Rectangle(invaders[Count].GetXPos(), invaders[Count].GetYPos(),invaderImg.Width, invaderImg.Height);

if (rectinvader.Intersects(rectlaucher))
   {
    this.Exit();
}
```

values for code:

```
launcherXPos = 512;

            invaderDirection = -1;
            invaderSpeed = 20;

            invader = new invader[55]; //displays the number entered of 'invaders'

            int XPos = 512;
            int YPos = 100;
```

Comment: Your values are wrong, and you are the only one who can figure out why. The code you gave should be fine.

Comment: the values seem fine, could you recheck the edited version above please frey, thanks kuttah x.

Comment: The code still looks fine. I think your logic elsewhere must be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are drawing some of your elements with an origin point other than Zero?

One way to try to fix this is to set a breakpoint at the collision that will be triggered only when you hit Space. Start playing the game, and when you should intersect, hit space, and go over the values you set in the rectangles. Try figuring out why they don't represent what's really going on.

Comment: Wow, that space breakpoint thing is AWESOME, I wonder why I never thought of it before :)